# How can I get a custom time

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I tried these code to pass in a custom time as a Timestamp type

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
x=pd.Timestamp(1/12/2020)  
print(x)  
y=pd.to_datetime(x,unit="s")   
print(y)
```

I am getting this result:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

while I should get have the real datetime

Comment: Use a string: `x=pd.Timestamp('1/12/2020', dayfirst=True)` (or `dayfirst=False` is 12 is the day). `1/12/2020` is giving a float (`4.12e-5`) !

Comment: you need to pass the string, not a number (yes `1/12/2020` is a number), to `Timestamp` like this `x=pd.Timestamp('1/12/2020', format='%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: your statement `x=pd.Timestamp(1/12/2020)` is executed as `1/12` result of that is used to execute `0.08333/2020` which is `0.000004125...` So the `pd.Timestamp(0.000004125)` is the first day which is `1970-01-01 00:00:00` Instead use what @mozway said or @Quang said